# TypeError: 'Logger' object is not callable when try to use already created logger object

Tags: python, logging

I have some use case where classes are inherited. In base class I have created logger object

```
import logging

class abc():
   logging.basicConfig(filename=r"D:\logger.txt",format="%(asctime)s %(message)s",filemode="w")
   abcd=logging.getLogger()
   abcd.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

and in derived class I tried to use the same object

```
from test import abc
import logging
class pqr(abc):
  p=logging.getLogger('abcd')
  p.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  def you(self):
    self.p("Ad")

 obj=pqr()
 obj.you()
```

but I am getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Test\test2.py", line 9, in <module>
obj.you()
 File "d:\Test\test2.py", line 7, in you
self.p("Ad")
TypeError: 'Logger' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this code.  You've provided three pieces, but included some disconnected components.  Let's review at the pieces:

```
class abc():
   logging.basicConfig(filename=r"D:\logger.txt",
                       format="%(asctime)s %(message)s",
                       filemode="w")
   abcd=logging.getLogger()
   abcd.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

You've set up a class `abc`, initialized the `logging`1 configuration, and created a class attribute `abcd` ... which you don't refer to in your later code, so I'm not sure why it's in your posting.

```
class pqr(abc):
  p=logging.getLogger('abcd')
  p.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

You derive a class `pqr` from your previous class.  Then you instantiate a new logger labeled "abcd", make it a class attribute, and set its reporting level.  *Note that this is a new logger, not the one you created in `abc`.

We're fine so far.  However ...

```
# In pqr:
    def you(self):
        self.p("Ad")

# Main
obj=pqr()
obj.you()
```

obj.p (the `self.p` in method `you`) is the `pqr` class logger.  You've tried to call the logger object as a whole.  It's not a method or function; it's an entire logger object.  If you're expecting to log something, you have to call an appropriate method, such as `self.p.info(<your message>)`.

Comment: got it @Prune.It was really helpful